# Custom comparator<String> issue in java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am currently making a natural sorting algorithm in Java. And the requirement is to make it run fast. 
Given an input String list, [1!, 10!, 100, 100!, 2]. The expected output order is [1!, 2, 10!,100, 100!]. As you can see they sort digit number first and then compare the value. However it is giving me headache when designing the cases.

Here is my thoughts when designing this problem.

Given String `a`, `b`.
(Edit: The input values could be 100!90!10!1234 with multiple "!" inside.Sorry for not mentioning earlier.The input will have english letter as well. But current version could handle it like a boss)

I create four index `(ind_a1, ind_a2, ind_b1, ind_b2)`

Case 1: If either `ind_a1` or `ind_b1` touch `!`, then return `-1`

Case 2: If either `ind_a1` or `ind_b1` touch the end of the string - 1 return `-1` (The current problem occurs right here in Case 2)

Case 3: When both index touch `!`,

Case 3.1: 
Check if `a.substring(ind_a2, ind_a1) == (b.substring(ind_b2, ind_b1)`
If they are equal means the previous values are the same. For example:
`1258!100` and `1258!10`. 
`a.substring(ind_a2, ind_a1) = (b.substring(ind_b2, ind_b1) = 1258`

Case 3.2:If they are not equal, then it just returns the previous compare values.

Here is my full code.

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
        int ind_a1 = 0 ,ind_a2 = 0;
        int ind_b1 = 0 ,ind_b2 = 0;
        int length_a = a.length();
        int length_b = b.length();
        int result = a.compareTo(b);
        char char_a, char_b;


        while(true)
        {
            char_a = a.charAt(ind_a1);
            char_b = b.charAt(ind_b1);
            //check if a or b is an empty String
            if(length_a == 0 || length_b ==0) {
                return length_a - length_b;
            }

            //Case 1）
            if(char_a == '!' && char_b != '!') {
                return -1;
            }
            if(char_b == '!' && char_a != '!') {
                return +1;
            }
            //Case 2: I NEED HELP HERE
            if(ind_a1 == length_a-1 || ind_b1 == length_b-1 ) {
                return length_a - length_b;
            }

            //Case 2 corner case, if both string has same length
            if(length_a == length_b) {
                return result;
            }

            //Case 3, if both index touch "!"   
            if(char_a =='!' && char_b == '!' ) {
                //Case 3.1
                if(a.substring(ind_a2, ind_a1) == (b.substring(ind_b2, ind_b1))) {
                    ind_a2 = ind_a1;
                    ind_b2 = ind_b1;
                }
                //Case 3.2
                else {
                    return a.substring(ind_a2,ind_a1).compareTo(b.substring(ind_b2,ind_b1));
                }                       
            }       
            ind_a1++;
            ind_b1++;
        }


    }

}
```

The current output order is [2, 1!, 10!, 100, 100!]. I know it doesnt work because 2 has less index then 1! so it will return -1. However is there anyway to adjust the code (or make it better, I would be so grateful) to make it work ?

(Example, Given input of [A5,a5,A5!,a5!,!A,!a,A,a,1,!]

The output should be  [!, !A, !a, 1, A, a, A5, A5!, a5! ])

Comment: i feel you are complication the Comparator logic

Comment: @Deadpool Yes I am in pain right now

Comment: @jimmyzhang What's the expected output for `[1!, 10!, 100, 100!, 2 , 2!, 22!, 22, 100 , 3]`?

Comment: @vivek_23 the output should be [1!, 2, 2!, 3, 22, 22!, 100, 100!]

Comment: @second Yes and the input could have multiple "!". For example 1258!100!10!900 as one input

Comment: So only `numbers` and `!` are allowed? what about `!1` or `5!!5`?

Comment: @second That is an excellent question! I didnt even think about that. The input will include only "!" , letters and numbers.

Comment: @jimmyzhang That clears things up a bit but I am still confused. In `1258!100!10!900`  what do we do with multiple `!` ? What's the output for `[1258!100!10!900,1258!100!10!9000,125!100!10!900,12510010900]` ?

Comment: @second I think the code now can handle !1. But we dont have to deal with 5!!5 at the moment

Comment: @second Sorry. But my version of code right now can handle english letter so i didnt think about it

Comment: How are the letters supposed to be ordered in comparison to the number and `!` ? (By now I assume your input is the complete range of alphanumeric + `!`)

Comment: @second For example, a= abcd!1258!100, b =abc!1258!100. The output order should be  b, a

Comment: @second It should be [!, !A, !a, 1, A, a, A5, A5!, a5! ]

Comment: Please mention that your input is alphanumeric as well. If I understand it correctly sort order should be: `! < A < a < Z < z < 0 < 9` - nah, still seems to be wrong ... the `!` is kinda ambigious

Comment: Write some tests for your `compare(..)`-method and if the result differs from what you expect, try debugging.

Comment: @second Its according to ASCII code. "!" has the least value

Comment: What if we have "!!!!" & A, Which one is greater. As ! have ASCII value 33 this implies !!!! will be 33*4= 132 and A have 65. Also Arrays.asList("1!", "1!!", "10!", "100!", "100", "2", "A"); let us know expected value of mentioned List

Comment: @Psingh We dont have to deal with "!!!!"  scenario. The expected value should be [2, A, 1!, 10!, 100, 100! ]

Comment: Updated my answer to point out your inconsistent expectations for different testcases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Added the test case you mentioned before, to point out there inconsistency.

---

Give this a try. I am still not sure whether this covers all your input requirements, but works for the following testcases:

```
input: [A5,a5,A5!,a5!,!A,!a,A,a,1,!]
expected output: [!, !A, !a, 1, A, a, A5, a5, A5!, a5!]
```

```
input: [1!, 1!!, 10!, 100!, 100, 2, A]
expected output: [2, A, 1!, 1!!, 10!, 100, 100!]
```

However for this testcase:

```
input: [1!, 10!, 100, 100!, 2 , 2!, 22!, 22, 100 , 3]
expected output: [1!, 2, 2!, 3, 22, 22!, 100, 100!]
```

the output is different.
You expectations seem to be inconsistent in this case, as this example has a **different ordering** for the elements 2 & 1!.

As long as that is the case there isnt really any point in trying to answer your question.

---

```
    Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

            int minSize = Math.min(o1.length(), o2.length());
            int index = 0;

            while (index < minSize) {

                char c1 = o1.charAt(index);
                char c2 = o2.charAt(index);

                if (c1 != c2) {

                    if (o1.length() == o2.length()) {
                        return c1 - c2;
                    }

                    if (c1 == '!') {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (c2 == '!') {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    return o1.length() - o2.length();
                }

                index++;
            }

            if (o1.length() == index) {
                if (o2.length() == index) {
                    return 0;
                }

                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you soooo much

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... S) {
    List a = Arrays.asList("1!", "10!", "100!", "100", "2");
    Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int oo1 = 0;
            int oo2 = 0;

            if (o1.contains("!")) {
                oo1 = 1;
                o1 = o1.replace("!", "");
            }

            if (o2.contains("!")) {
                oo2 = 1;
                o2 = o2.replace("!", "");
            }

            int result = (Integer.valueOf(o1) - Integer.valueOf(o2));

            return result == 0 ? oo1 - oo2 : result;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(a);
```

### }

As per comment

> @Psingh We dont have to deal with "!!!!" scenario. The expected value should be [2, A, 1!, 10!, 100, 100! ]

```
public static void main(String... S) {
    List a = Arrays.asList("1!", "1!!", "10!", "100!", "100", "2", "A");
    Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int ooo1 = 0;
            int ooo2 = 0;

            for (char i : o1.toCharArray()) {
                ooo1 += (int) i;
            }
            for (char i : o2.toCharArray()) {
                ooo2 += (int) i;
            }
            return ooo1 - ooo2;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: this will return that 100 and 100! are equal. they are not.

Comment: I will be dealing with a lot of 128 bit values and cannot use split function because time cost problem

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, Consider user use case too.
Jimmy, Removed split

Comment: @Psingh: currently we have established that o1 and o2 might not be numbers at all.

Comment: Yes, I have read comments afterwards, Alphanumeric thing should be mentioned in the question description explicitly. Anyways thinking...

Comment: Why do you think that the sum of the character values would lead to the desired sorting order?

Comment: @second the provided order are based on ASCII order asc eg: 2 have 50, A have 65, 1! have 49+33 and soo on.

Comment: Desired output plz? @second

Comment: Its more complicated than that. Try with this: `Arrays.asList("A5","a5","A5!","a5!","!A","!a","A","a","1","!");` You wont get the desired result. I have a solution which works for this, but doesn`t work for the testcase you used :(

Comment: Its in the question: The output should be [!, !A, !a, 1, A, a, A5, a5, A5!, a5! ]). But he missed the a5, I assume its third to last